# Different values on Tensorflow matrix multiplication vs. manual calculation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am working on an optimsation on tensorflow where matrix multiplication gives differnt values compared to manual calculation. The difference is just on the 6 decimal and i know its very tiny but as epochs goes on i get quite different elbo values.

Here is a small example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0.2751678 , 0.00671141, 0.39597315, 0.4966443 , 0.17449665,
       0.00671141, 0.32214764, 0.02013423, 1.        , 0.40939596,
       0.        , 0.9597315 , 0.4161074 , 0.        , 0.2147651 ,
       0.22147651, 0.5771812 , 0.70469797, 0.44966444, 0.36241612]],dtype=np.float32)

b = np.array([[2.6560298e-04, 0.0000000e+00, 7.9084152e-01, 8.2393251e-03,
       0.0000000e+00, 9.8140877e-01, 6.5296537e-01, 2.6107374e-01,
       1.2936005e-03, 5.2952105e-01, 2.2449312e-01, 9.9892569e-01,
       8.4370503e-04, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 9.5679509e-03, 0.0000000e+00]],dtype=np.float32)
a_t = tf.constant(a)
b_t = tf.constant(b.T)
```

**Matrix multiplication**

```
tf.matmul(a_t,b_t)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[1.7209427]], dtype=float32)>
```

**Manual calculation**

```
tf.reduce_sum(tf.transpose(a_t)*b_t)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.7209429>
```

What is the reason for this difference? Is ther a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the results from different algorithms that rely on float arithmetic. It's completely normal to get different results at the last significant decimal digit. Actually, that is the best case scenario. Sometimes the difference will be even higher.

For example, you may try different values for `n` in the following code:

```
from numpy import random as np_random
from numpy import matmul as np_matmul
from numpy import multiply as np_multiply
from numpy import transpose as np_transpose
from numpy import sum as np_sum

n = 10

for i in range(10000):
    a = np_random.rand(1,n).astype('float32')
    b = np_random.rand(n,1).astype('float32')
    c = np_matmul(a,b)
    d = np_sum(np_multiply(a,np_transpose(b)),axis=1)
    e = c-d
    if abs(e) > 0:
        print("%.16f" % c)
        print("%.16f" % d)
        print("%e" % e)
        break
```

Anyway, single-precision floating-point format (float32) gives from 6 to 9 significant decimal digits precision. If you need more precision, you still have double precision (float64).

More information can be found in [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) from Python Documentation.